# sum of x^n i have the sum and n, how do i find x?

Tags: calculus

sum of x^n I have the sum and n, how do i find x?

you have to excuse me if the question is stupid i`m kind of bad at math,

Comment: This is not clear.  If you are talking about [Geometric Series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series) then there is a closed form for the sum which you could solve for $x$.

Comment: i do not know if it is geometric series or not. i have actual number for sum(100,000,000) and i know the number for n (150).

Comment: Well, I don't see how we can guess what sum you are looking at.  What are you summing over?  Given that you seem to feel that both $x,n$ are fixed...there's nothing left to sum over!

Comment: that is my problem i have bin given the result and being ask abut the formula...

Comment: the orginal question:                                                                                     
Prepare a proposal for level distribution for players based on the level of experience (xp) with the following assumptions.
 - The experience of the player rises from 1xp to 1,000,000,000,000,000xp
 - We need 250 levels
 - to reach level 150 player should collect 100,000,000xp

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand.  There's no sum mentioned in that anywhere.  It looks like you are just being asked to come up with a function $f(n)$ such that $f(1)=1, f(150)=10^8, f(250)=10^{15}$.

Comment: Ok so how can i come up whit this function? and thank you for responding to me.

Comment: Well, I have no idea how precise you need to be.  You could guess at a form, like $f(n)=c^{n-1}$...if we take $c=1.1316$ you get $f(1)=1, f(150)\approx 10^8$, and $f(250)\approx 3\times 10^{13}$.  That's not terrible.

Comment: If you take $c=1.14879$ you get $f(1)=1, f(250)=10^{15}$ and $f(150)\approx 946,027,181$ which might be better.

Comment: this is exactly what i need. how do you come up whit 1.1316?

Comment: For that one, I solved $f(150)=c^{149}=10^8\implies \log_{10}c=\frac 8{149}\implies c=10^{8/149}=1.131595665$ to more places.

Comment: If you need these things to be exact, you could just take straight line interpolation from $(1,1)$ to $(150,10^8)$ and then another straight line from $(150,10^8)$ to $(250,10^{15})$, but that seems worse to me.

Comment: thank you man you are a god and even batter a life saver.

Comment: Good luck! $\quad $

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds to me with the xp you are asking $$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{149} x^{n-1}=100,000,000$$ find $x$ given the $a$ and $n$. This can be done by using the formula for the partial sums of the geometric series which is $$S_n= \frac{a_1(1-r^n)}{1-r}$$ where $a_1$ is your term, in this case 1, and r is the common ratio in this case $x$. Your $S_n$ will be $100,000,000$, I will leave the algebra to you. Note this works as long as $r \neq 1$.